# Resizing Java JFrame changes color of a Graphics component

Tags: java

I just started working with Java Graphics and I wrote two classes:

```java
/*Paintr.java file*/

import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.util.Random;

public class Paintr extends JPanel {
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    Random gen = new Random();
    g.setColor(new Color(gen.nextInt(256),gen.nextInt(256),gen.nextInt(256)));
    g.fillRect(15, 25, 100, 20);
    g.drawString("Current color: "+ g.getColor(),130,65);
  }
}
```

And the main class:

```java
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class App {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Drawing stuff.");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    Paintr board = new Paintr();
    frame.add(board);
    frame.setSize(400, 300);
    frame.setResizable(true);
    frame.setVisible(true);

  }
}
```

Now if I compile this and run, it works. It displays my random color. What I don't understand is why after I resize the Frame it changes the color that is displayed. Why does it recalls this block of code:

```java
g.setColor(new Color(gen.nextInt(256),gen.nextInt(256),gen.nextInt(256)));
g.fillRect(15, 25, 100, 20);
g.drawString("Current color: "+ g.getColor(),130,65);
```

Comment: If you don't want this to happen, consider drawing your random color to a BufferedImage, and then drawing that in the `paintComponent(...)` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `paintComponent()` function is called every time the Frame resizes. This is to allow developers to resize other things to fit new sizes!

If you don't want this to happen define your colour as a variable

```
Color color = new Color(gen.nextInt(256),gen.nextInt(256),gen.nextInt(256));
```

Then in your `paintComponent()` function just paint that colour.

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    super.paintComponent(g);
    this.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(15, 25, 100, 20);
    g.drawString("Current color: "+ g.getColor(),130,65);
}
```